# Set Adobe as default program via Group Policy?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, defaults

My question is about default program via Group Policy. Basically what i need is - set Adobe as default windows PDF reader via Group Policy. I have been trying to do this for a while now, but haven't found a way yet. Any help is appreciated!

[Useful Info]
( Windows: 10 )
( Group Policy: Windows server 2012 R2 )

Thanks.

Comment: Adobe is a company. What specific Adobe product are you referring to? At any rate, this is the correct method for setting the default app associations in Windows 10 - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsinternals/2017/10/25/windows-10-how-to-configure-file-associations-for-it-pros/

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Group Policy registry preferences.

[This post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/registry-location-of-default-windows-10-apps/62fc4cf6-3c94-44a7-9efc-8ff7aaaa851c) should get you in the right direction for editing default applications via the registry on Windows 10.

Test first on a single computer so you know which keys to create/modify. Then duplicate that solution in a registry preference.

[This post](https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/group-policy-preferences-1-deploying-registry-settings.html) explains how to deploy a registry preference.